# Taking snapshot of entire OS

Tags: windows, snapshot

I was wondering if anyone knew of free software to take an OS snapshot.

Something that would also compare and list the differences between the two different snapshots.

Comment: What OS exactly?

Comment: Windows Xp or later.

Comment: I think VSS (Volume Shadow Copy Service) can do this (technically), but I don't know if there's a way to use it the way we want to (i.e. to revert back to a differential snapshot, etc.).  [More Info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384625(v=vs.85).aspx]

Answer (score 3):

1. Microsoft Image Backup (Available on Windows 7)
2. CloneZilla

Thoose are the two I know of that are free.
There are a large number of proprietary ones available for windows though.