# Create a snapshot of the Windows session this very moment

Tags: windows, hibernate, snapshot

Is it possible to create a snapshot (just as VirtualBox does) of a real Windows system as of the state this very moment?

If I hibernate, RAM at the moment is dumped to the hard disk. Is it possible to dump this on demand, continuing the system usage?

One idea would be creating the hibernation files without actually shutting down the system. Can they be generated without actual hibernation?

Potential usage: saving in-progress operation which can't be saved the usual way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Snapshot of a Windows 7 System](http://superuser.com/questions/716494/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-windows-7-system), [Taking snapshot of entire OS](http://superuser.com/questions/296091/taking-snapshot-of-entire-os)

Comment: Nope. These are about dumping the Windows partition (backing up), mine is about creating a snapshot of the RAM (so in particular the current state of the open apps)

Comment: The question says: of a real system (not virtualized), so the question is still open. And PLEASE, DO NOT MARK IT AS A DUPLICATE WHEN IT ISN'T ONE.

Comment: And restoring and dumping one process? Is it feasible?